# Django DRF Django-filters how to provide a default value if filter argument was not provided?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

So in this example from the documentation of django-filters, how would I set a default value for max_price if max_price was not provided as filter option with the API call?

```
class ProductFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    min_price = filters.NumberFilter(field_name="price", lookup_expr='gte')
    max_price = filters.NumberFilter(field_name="price", lookup_expr='lte')

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['category', 'in_stock']


class ProductList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_class = ProductFilter
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways

1-through the method argumen->You can enter the desired query at the desired price        [django-filter method](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html#method)

2- The front end will call the endpoint for the first time with your desired value and param